# Javascript variable in XMLHttpReques on live server resets to nothing

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm a bit confused by this because on my localhost it worked out..

When I run my code I generate a variable before hand `randomid` Now I want to use this id inside the response of my XMLHttpRequest but a console.log shows that the variable `randomid` has changed:

```
var randomid = "8bqfqm2q";

console.log("../export/" + randomid + ".ff" );

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        console.log("../export/" + randomid + ".ff" );
    }
}
xhr.open('POST', "../phpfile.php", true);
xhr.send(new FormData(document.getElementById("myform")));
```

The console prints:

```
../export/8bqfqm2q.ff
../export/.ff
```

However when I do this:

```
document.getElementById("passfilterid").value = "8bqfqm2q";
```

and pass `document.getElementById("passfilterid").value` instead of `randomid` to the console log.. it works..

I do not understand, what happened? This code worked perfectly fine on my localhost, so I'm not sure what to do. I'm not getting any errors either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add either a callbackfunction to the xhttp object and pass a value to it or you can add a property to the xhttp-object and retrieve it inside the function.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.randomid = "8bqfqm2q";
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        console.log("../export/" + this.randomid + ".ff" );
    }
}
```